# Independent testing on scaled deployments in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to figure out the approach to achieve the following.

1. I have a multiple deployments for a few components that together complete my application. For simplicity, let us assume there is a frontend, a backend and a database.
2. When I deploy (with 1 pod each) all the components and release the frontend behind an external IP, I can access the application. Internally the network connections are as follows. `Frontend 1 -> Backend 1 -> Database 1`
3. My requirement of scaling is such that when I create a second copy of deployments, I want to access a completely independent (from the first deployment) scenario like `Frontend 2 -> Backend 2 -> Database 2`. The use case is to support multiple parallel testings on different data in the database. For instance if `Test A` is going on and `Test B` is required, we spin up the application and start an independent testing on that.

How can I accomplish this?

With what I have tried till now, the load balancer service that exposes the frontend to the external IP will balance the traffic to either `Frontend 1` or `Frontend 2` and the same way for the backend and database they connect to. I can add all containers to a single pod as a single deployment too, so that the backend and database are decoupled from the other deployments through localhost connections but the frontend that I connect to would still not be as desired.

Can I setup a 1-1 mapping in the load balancer service? Am I missing something crucial here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load balancer isn't meant to balance your traffic between different `Deployments` but between a set of `Pods` within one `Deployment`. If you have only one `Pod` in each of them, there is actually nothing to be balanced. If your `Frontend1` `Deployment` consists let's say of 3 `Pods`, `Loadbalancer` takes care to distribute your traffic evenly among those 3 `Pods`. As far as I understand your `Frontend1` and `Frontend2` are two separate deployments and you want to be able to switch your traffic flexibly, not just part of it, but the whole traffic between `Frontend1` and `Frontend2`, right ?

It can be done quite easily however much better approach would be using two separate `LoadBalancers` for `Frontend1` and `Frontend2` `Deployments`. Let's suppose you have an external `LoadBalancer` defined in `lb.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-loadbalancer-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-prod
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

As you can see it uses `app: nginx-prod` selector which means it selects only `Pods` which have `app` label with `nginx-prod` value defined. To switch your traffic to `nginx-dev` Pods that are part of your `Frontend2` `Deployment` you need only to update this file by changing `nginx-prod` to `nginx-dev` and apply new configuration with the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f lb.yaml
```

Your external traffic will be immediately directed to `Pods` managed by your `Frontend2` `Deployment`. You can test it easily using two following yaml manifests:

**Deployment 1** (it can be your `Frontend1`):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-prod
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-prod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-prod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: workdir
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      initContainers:
      - name: install
        image: busybox
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
        args: ["echo Welcome on Prod! > /work-dir/index.html"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: workdir
          mountPath: "/work-dir"
      volumes:
      - name: workdir
        emptyDir: {}
```

**Deployment 2** (it can be your `Frontend2`):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-dev
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-dev
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-dev
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: workdir
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      initContainers:
      - name: install
        image: busybox
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
        args: ["echo Welcome on Dev! > /work-dir/index.html"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: workdir
          mountPath: "/work-dir"
      volumes:
      - name: workdir
        emptyDir: {}
```

When it comes to balancing requests coming from your frontend `Pods` to your backend `Pods` it can be done in a very similar way but you don't need for that `LoadBalancer` but simple `ClusterIP` Service (`ClusterIP` can be omitted in `Service` definition as it is the default type) like the one below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: prod-backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Note that it has `app: prod-backend` selector. Imagine that your `dev` set of Pods managed by `Backend2` `Deployment` has different value of this label. It can be e.g. `dev-backend`. Once you change selector in your `Service` from `app: prod-backend` to `app: dev-backend`, all your traffic coming so far from your frontend `Pods` to `Backend1` will be redirected to your `Backend2` `Pods` (labelled as `dev-backend`). I'm sharing it only to show you that this is also possible but such approach doesn't make any sense. As it comes to `LoadBalancer`, I agree that creating additional `LoadBalancer` involves additional costs but it isn't the case with simple `ClusterIP` `Services`. So in this case you should define two different `Services`, each of them using different selector. Then using Service's FQDN which will be different for `Backend1` and `Backend2` `Service` you can direct your traffic accordingly from `Frontend1` and `Frontend2`.

I hope this clarifies a bit more the use of `LoadBalancer` and `ClusterIP` `Service`. If something isn't completely clear, don't hesitate to reach out and ask additional questions.